# Computing row-wise zscores in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe contains numeric and character columns as shown below.

```
> df 
A   B   C   D E G
a1  b1  c1  1 2 3
a2  b2  c2  4 5 6
...
```

I want to compute row-wise zscores for numeric columns (D, E and G) using dplyr. I tried:

```
> df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~scale(., center=T, scale=T))
> A   B   C   D E G
a1  b1  c1  NA NA NA
a2  b2  c2  NA NA NA
```

I'm unable to understand why NA is being returned. Any inputs on how to achieve what I want to do is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? By doing this `rowwise()` you are essentially doing, for example for column D in the first row, `scale(1)`. Try running that and seeing what you get...

Comment: For column D first row, I want: 1 - mean(c(1,2,3)) / sd(c(1,2,3))
For column E first row, I want: 2 - mean(c(1,2,3)) / sd(c(1,2,3))
and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
df[4:6] <- t(scale(t(df[4:6]), center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(out = pmap(across(where(is.numeric)), 
  ~ scale(c(...), center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)), .keep = 'unused') %>% 
  unnest_wider(out) %>% 
  mutate(across(D:G, c))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using dplyr?

Comment: @swathi.upadhya try the update